# index will work for sql case expression with substr in where clause in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with ex: name varchar column. I have a normal index on name column

and I have a view with case expression for the name column.
ex:

```
case when name ~ E'^\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+' then name 
when name ~ E'\\.(ac|co|gov|ltd|me|net|org|com)\\...$' then substring(name from E'.*?([^.]+.[^.]+.[^.]+)$')
else ELSE substring(name, E'.*?([^.]+.[^.]+)$') as name,
```

later I am running a query on the view with name filter.
will my index work on the name column.

Comment: You can put [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE `](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) in front of any query see exactly what it uses.

Comment: I would create a generated column in the table based on that expression. Then create an index on the generated column and use that in your view instead of the name column

Answer (score 0):

Index on a column used by `case` in a view will likely not be used for filtering on that view. But you can use that `case` expression to build and index that *will* be used.

```sql
create index on yourtable (
  (--double parentheses are mandatory to use an expression in index definition
    case 
        when name ~ E'^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' 
          then name 
        when name ~ E'\.(ac|co|gov|ltd|me|net|org|com)\...$' 
          then substring(name from E'.?([^.]+.[^.]+.[^.]+)$') 
        else substring(name, E'.?([^.]+.[^.]+)$')
    end --`as alias` not allowed here
  )
);
```

Or, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74556029/index-will-work-for-sql-case-expression-with-substr-in-where-clause-in-postgres#comment131609883_74556029) by [@a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name), if you can add columns to the table:

```
alter table yourtable add column processed_name text generated always as (
  case 
        when name ~ E'^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' 
          then name 
        when name ~ E'\.(ac|co|gov|ltd|me|net|org|com)\...$' 
          then substring(name from E'.?([^.]+.[^.]+.[^.]+)$') 
        else substring(name, E'.?([^.]+.[^.]+)$')
    end) stored;

create index on yourtable (processed_name);
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/J81uLap5). Note that whether an index will be used or not depends a lot on how you filter your query and what it does. Both the generated column and the index are expected to add some overhead to your inserts, which you'll have to test on your setup to see if it's tolerable for you. Most of the time, in typical scenarios it's hard to notice.

Comment: will this does not take time at the time of insertion as I will get millions of records for every one minute

Comment: It will add [some](https://dbfiddle.uk/gS7e2JXb) overhead. How perceivable it will be depends on what, how and how often you insert.